# call of a function in another function in C

Tags: c

I was wondering how I could call a function in an other function in C.
For example, I created the function :

```
void speed (int argc, char** argv)
```

from a hyperterminal, I type 1 or 2 and I get something written on the hyperterminal.
In another function called:

```
void menu (int argc, char ** argv)
```

I want to call the previous function: `speed(...)`. I dont know what to fill in for `...`.

thanks
jim

Comment: @Manoj R: Hyper Terminal is a simple character based remote terminal program included with Windows, although it hasn't been installed by default since about Windows98/Windows 2000.

Answer (score 4):

```
void menu (int argc, char ** argv)
{
   speed(argc, argv); // this is how you call a function
}
```

For this to work either speed needs to be defined above menu, or a declaration of it needs to be before it or in a header.  Declaration of speed looks like

```
void speed (int argc, char ** argv);
```

Answer (score 1):

What Franco was talking about are called *function prototypes*. C parses (or compiles) your code from top down, so if it hits your call to *speed* before it hits your declaration of *speed* it complains. To workaround this, you need to create a *function prototype* as a *forward reference* to the function. Generally, it is good practice to write prototypes for all your functions at the top of your code, or in another file (aka the *header* file) and #include it.

```
/* helloworld.h */
void speed (int , char **);
void menu (int , char **);



/* helloworld.c */
#include "helloworld.h"
void menu (int argc, char **argv){
   speed (argc, argc);
}
```